In flaUI,FindFirstDescendant doesn't work
In flaUI, if the FindFirstDescendant method neither returns null nor the expected element, and causes the code to interrupt execution, the exception cannot be caught using try catch
i want it can be return null or the right elemnt when it appear

Probably you are not using the right condition. Can you paste the code?
